# How can I read a line from a file and check if that row contains an #include for call an header file?

Tags: c

I am trying to read all the content of a .c file and print out in another .o file all the source code of the first file, replacing all the `#include <....>` in this way:

- Input: `#include<string.h>`
- Ouput: `"string.h"`

I have to work in pure C, without the chance to use any C++ libraries

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Just get your compiler to write its preprocessor output, `-E` with clang or gcc and there is a similar option for visual studio

Comment: c++ is not an add-on to c as one might get the impression reading your text, they are two different languages. I removed the c++ tag as this question seems to be about c

Comment: What parts of this problem do you know how to solve? Do you have an approach in mind? Do you know how to read a line and write a line? Are you familiar with `strncmp()`?

Comment: Yeah, I know how to use strncmp @Beta

Comment: And my other questions? If you want to learn to write software, you must make an effort.

Answer (score 1):

A simple sed on your file maybe?

```sh
sed 's/.*#include *\(<|"\)\(.*\)\(>|"\).*/"\2"/' < input.c > output.o
```

Comment: What if the `#include` statement appears within a comment?

Comment: @GovindParmar the comment gets modified, who cares? Obviously not OP or they wouldn't ask how to write a C parser ^^

Comment: if the #include appeares within a comment I have just to ignore it. @Govin